# How can I write the latex special character $\bar{T}$ in matplotlib axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, latex

I would like to write the latex math mode symbol $\bar{T}$ in the axes label of a plot made with matplotlib. The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html) states that math mode is not supported so I tried

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\displaystyle \={T}$',fontsize=12)
```

and

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\={T}$',fontsize=12)
```

which gives the errors

```
matplotlib.pyparsing.ParseFatalException: Expected end of math '$'
$\displaystyle \={T}$ (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

and

```
    raise ParseFatalException(msg + "\n" + s)
matplotlib.pyparsing.ParseFatalException: Expected end of math '$'
$\={T}$ (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
>>>
```

Is there a way to write this symbol in the axes labels using matplotlib? I have been able to write other latex axes labels but I have never used any of these [special characters.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters)

Answer (score 4):

The documentation page you linked to was describing calling out to Latex to provide formatted text, but matplotlib has its own builtin math expression parser that can deal with most Latex math commands just fine, without actually running an external latex command. Unless you've specifically set up your matplotlib install to use an external install of Latex, you're still using the builtin math parser, which can deal with `\bar{}` just fine:

```
plt.plot(range(5), range(5))
plt.xlabel(r'$\bar{T}$',fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Comment: To get the bar to span through more characters we can use `\overline`